How to traverse a base R list vertically/by rows using R's characteristics
I am new to R and for a homework assignment we have to extract the first elements of each column from a list to sum these up. My current code seems to work fine but it feels like I am not using the inhert R characteristics to efficiently work with the list. (Instead it feels like I'm just applying methods to deal with lists I learned in Java)
I have a list:
mylist <- list(points_ex1=c(15,18,12), points_ex2=c(9,16,8), points_ex3=c(83,95,39))
and I am trying to sum up the first/second/third value of each vector respectively. For the first column this would result in 15+9+83=107
Currently I am using two nested for loops to traverse the list and then appending each element to a temporary vector, who's sum is then appended to a vector of the total points.
total_points <- NULL #object to append total scores to
for (i in 1:3){
  temp <- NULL #object to append points to
  for (j in 1:3){
    temp <- append(temp, mylist[[j]][i]) #appending the i-th element of each test score vector, before appending that sum
                                         #to the total_points vector and continuing with the next row
  }
  total_points <- append(total_points, sum(temp))
}

This works as expected, but feels like it does not use any useful R characteristics (e.g. a function like sapply()). Are there any good options to improve this code?
As this is my first question here please do tell me if I am breaking any conventions/netequitte on this site! Thank you.

When list items all have the same length, it's usually easier to have them as a data frame. I would do
mylist |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  rowSums()
# [1] 107 129  59

If you don't want to rely on the list being convertible to a data frame, and instead want to extract the ith element of each item and sum them, then I would do it like this:
i = 1
sapply(mylist, "[", i) |>  ## extract `i`th element 
  sum()                    ## and sum
# [1] 107

Which you could then repeat for whichever values of i you want.

The second solution is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

There's a lot (of good stuff) going on with this answer that can be tricky for a beginner (I imagine). [ being used as a function and i actually being passed in as an argument to [. I like your method but I'd probably write something like this to more easily parse it: i <- 1; sapply(mylist, \(x) x[i]) |> sum(). Cheers

One way to solve your problem:
rowSums(simplify2array(mylist))
# [1] 107 129  59


In the sense of code golf I would like to add
> rowSums(list2DF(mylist))
[1] 107 129  59 


There is a n+1 solutions. For data manipulation data.frame/tibble is preferred. Possible way:
mylist <- list(points_ex1=c(15,18,12), points_ex2=c(9,16,8), points_ex3=c(83,95,39))

mylist |>
  as.data.frame()
#>   points_ex1 points_ex2 points_ex3
#> 1         15          9         83
#> 2         18         16         95
#> 3         12          8         39

But then we can rearrange the columns/rows a bit:
mylist |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  dplyr::mutate(n = dplyr::row_number()) |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(c(1:3)) |>
  dplyr::group_by(n) |>
  dplyr::reframe(sum(value))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>       n `sum(value)`
#>   <int>        <dbl>
#> 1     1          107
#> 2     2          129
#> 3     3           59

In fact, every solution which leads to proper results is a proper one. Just a matter of computing efficiency/code readability and reproducibility.
Created on 2024-11-05 with reprex v2.1.0

Your second code chunk can be reduced to data.frame(Sum = rowSums(as.data.frame(mylist))), writing row names as consecutive integers does not add much.
